# java.sql.SQLException: Connection Cache with this Cache Name is Disabled

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jakarta-ee, oc4j

I am trying to make a connection with the Oracle database, using the j2ee application running on OC4J. My data-sources.xml always works in our production and UAT environment. I tried to setup on my local desktop and it is not working.  The error message is --java.sql.SQLException: Connection Cache with this Cache Name is Disabled.

Oracle database version is:-

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
database.

Oracle database is on a virtual box, the host is window 10 and the guest machine is Fedora 23.

Any idea what might cause this?

thanks.

---

```
<managed-data-source name="OracleTM" connection-pool-name="Regency Connection Pool" 
       jndi-name="jdbc/GSTJOBS"/> 
<connection-pool name='Regency Connection Pool' min-connections='1' max-connections='5' 
     initial-limit='1' used-connection-wait-timeout='60' inactivity-timeout='60' 
     connection-retry-interval='1' max-connect-attempts='3' 
     validate-connection='false' num-cached-statements='1' time-to-live-timeout='-1' 
     abandoned-connection-timeout='-1' property-check-interval='900'> 

<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="Regency" 
     password="Regency" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Regency"/>
```

Comment: Don't add comments to extend/clarify your question. **Edit** the question (link below question text). Delete the comments. And make sure to format that XML correctly for human readability.

Comment: Please see if this helps. https://community.oracle.com/thread/695717

Comment: Hi OTM, I check the link but there is DNS suffix is provided as solution, but I am able to connect to the database using 
localhost with oracle tool toad; I am having problem with only when I am creating connection with web application. 

In my guest machine  .bash_profile the host name entry is below. 
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain; and in hostname localhost.localdomain
entry in /etc/hostname.Can you please explain more, above is the entry of the host file in my VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,I just change  the connection pool name(may have maintain in the session of oracle), as I change the connection pool name  and connection have started working.